# How to conditionally reset rolling max initial value/row in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max

I want to reset the the row where the dataframe starts to evaluate `rolling max`. I want to do this based on a column containing `True` or `False`. This is the expected output:

```
     number     condition     rolling_max
0    77         False         77
1    80         False         80
2    54         True          54 # starting max calculation from this point
3    23         False         54
4    60         False         60
5    100        False         100
6    15         False         100
7    119        False         119
8    10         True          10 # starting max calculation from this point
9    65         False         65
10   20         True          20 # starting max calculation from this point
```

How can I do this?

Comment: condition column seems to be redundant, no?

Comment: @Yuca I rolled back the edit, the comments are necessary to explain his question.  He wants to re-start a cumulative max each time his condition column is `True`

Comment: @user3483203 I know, but the condition is redundant,  you have true when previous value is larger than current value. So it is self contained. Main reason why I removed the remarks was to allow for a clean use of pd.read_clipboard :)

Comment: "you have true when previous value is larger than current value" - this is not the case. `condition` is specified separately.

Comment: from your example that's the case, or not? however, I have already explain the reason for my edit and I have no issue with it being roll backed :)

Comment: @Yuca Yes, your solution does the job. Can you help me with the same problem, but in case of a multiindex dataframe? Here I posted the question for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651800/how-to-conditionally-reset-a-rolling-maxs-initial-value-row-in-pandas-multiinde

Comment: I was able to solve this incase one has a MultiIndex dataframe. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52651800/how-to-conditionally-reset-a-rolling-maxs-initial-value-row-in-pandas-multiinde

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `cumsum` create the `groupby` key then using `cummax`

```
df.groupby(df.condition.cumsum()).number.cummax()
Out[889]: 
0      77
1      80
2      54
3      54
4      60
5     100
6     100
7     119
8      10
9      65
10     20
Name: number, dtype: int64
```