# How to conditionally reset a rolling max's initial value/row in pandas MultiIndex dataframe?

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, max, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe. Index columns are `Date` and `Symbol`. I want to reset the row where the dataframe starts to evaluate `rolling_max` of `number` for each `Symbol`. I want to do this based on a column containing `True` or `False`. If `condition` is `True` on a `Date` then `rolling_max` should be reset and calculate max from this `Date`. If `condition` is `False` then `rolling_max` should work 'normally' - taking the max of today's and yesterday's `number` for the given `Symbol`. The `condition` column has nothing to do with the `number` column (they do not depend on each other). This is the expected output:

```
                         number     condition     rolling_max
Date          Symbol     
1990-01-01    A          29         False         29
1990-01-01    B          7          False         7

1990-01-02    A          13         True          13 # Reset rolling max for 'A'
1990-01-02    B          2          False         7

1990-01-03    A          11         False         13
1990-01-03    B          52         True          52 # Reset rolling max for 'B'

1990-01-04    A          30         False         30
1990-01-04    B          1          False         52

1990-01-05    A          19         True          19 # Reset rolling max for 'A'
1990-01-05    B          65         False         65

1990-01-06    A          17         False         19
1990-01-06    B          20         True          20 # Reset rolling max for 'B'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this.

```
df['rolling_max'] = df.groupby(['Symbol',df.groupby('Symbol')['condition'].cumsum()])['number'].cummax()
```